# Query Syntax by Drug Class

Tags: api, openfda

I am interested in creating a dataset that only contains that class of drugs. I would prefer being able to search by the drug name, but entries for that field are masked. Does anyone know if I can search by and create a dataset by drug class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm Violet Wren, the tech lead of the openFDA dev team. Which endpoint are you searching for this information? A link to an example search would be great and I can help further from there.